# Accessing Contract Variables from JS Unit Tests

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, mocha

I am having trouble unit testing my contracts: I am using Mocha, Chai and calling `truffle test`

I am testing `LoanRecord.sol`

```
contract LoanRecord {
  public bool on;
  ...

  constructor(...){
    ...
    on = false;
   }

  function external turnOn(){
    on = true;
  }
}
```

And testing in record.test.js:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert
var LoanRecord = artifacts.require("../../contracts/record/LoanRecord.sol");

contract ('Record', function (accounts) {
    describe("#turnOn()", function () {
        it("should turn on a loan record instance", async function () {
            loanrecord = await LoanRecord.new(
                1,
                18,
                0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002,
                0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001, 
                "LOAN"
                );
            await assert.equal(loanrecord.on, false)
            await loanrecord.turnOn()
            await assert.equal(loanrecord.on, true)
        });
    });
```

However, I am recieving:

```
1) Contract: Record
       #turnOn()
         should turn on a loan record instance:
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to equal false
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/record.js:15:26)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Why does `loanrecord.on` return `[Function]` rather than a boolean type?

Fixed (with gitter@dwardu help too):

```
contract ('Record', function (accounts) {
    describe("#turnOn()", function () {
        it("should turn on a loan record instance", async function () {
            loanrecord = await LoanRecord.new(
                1,
                18,
                0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002,
                0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001, 
                "LOAN"
                );
            var on = await loanrecord.on()
            await assert.equal(on, false)
            await loanrecord.turnOn()
            var on = await loanrecord.on()
            await assert.equal(on, true)
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting is giving you a good hint about comparing function to a boolean value. This means one side of the comparison is a function and one is a variable (or value).

For each variable in your Solidity contracts, a public getter function is automatically generated. This means a function with signature `function on()` is automatically generated to access the value of the variable `on`. Therefore when accessing the variables you also have to access them through the getter functions.

Change your `await assert.equal(loanrecord.on, true)` to `await assert.equal(loanrecord.on(), true)` and it should work. Or you might need to `await` for `on()` function's value to be returned before comparing.

Comment: Can we set the variables?